# C# TO VB dont understand how to access entity objects?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have used entity framework quite a lot in c# and know what to do there, but how do I access the items in my list:

```
    Dim records As List(Of R3Delivery)
    records = threeContext.GetAllDeliverysByRecordId(41)
```

So that i can do this:

```
txtboxOrderNunber.Text=records.ordernumber
```

This is my function

```
Function GetAllDeliverysByRecordId(ByVal recorId As Int16) As List(Of R3Delivery)
    Dim retVal As New List(Of R3Delivery)
    retVal = (From u In dbContext.R3Delivery Where u.r3DeliveryId = recorId Select u).ToList()


    Return retVal

End Function
```

And also how would I save the updates using the above method thanks.

saveedit

```
    records.Item(0).qty = txtQty.Text
    records.Item(0).isDelivered = chkNotDelivered.Checked
    Try
        threeContext.dbContext.SaveChanges()
        MessageBox.Show("Changes saved to the database.")
        Close()
```

Comment: You save it exactly the same way as in C#.

Comment: @Styxxy look at my save edit their its saving ok but its not refreshing my gridview until i close the gridview window

Comment: @Styxxy I have another stitack here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011805/grid-only-updating-when-main-gridwindow-is-closed?noredirect=1#comment35149313_23011805

Comment: @Styxxy its saving ok but no matter what i do my gridview wont rebind to the new data any ideas

Comment: How do you bind the value? If you just set the value, it won't update, you'll have to update it yourself (rebind to the new values).

Answer (score 0):

I got the first bit ok I didnt no i had to use item(0).fieldname approcah like below

```
    Dim records As List(Of R3Delivery)
    records = threeContext.GetAllDeliverysByRecordId(41)
    txtQty.Text = records.Item(0).qty
```

but then how do i save the entity back when i make a change?

Comment: or don't return a list, just return the item?