# Grid only updating when main gridwindow is closed

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have to forms one containing a grid view then a popup that the user can edit the values of the gridview its saving the data ok but only when i close the main gridview window
[image]

But the data does not get refershed in the blow grid until i close the main form  I am calling the form from the double click of the grid

```
    Dim invId As Object = dgDeliverys.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("r3DeliveryId").Value
    Dim frmedit As New frmedit(invId)
    frmedit.ShowDialog()
    BindGrid()
```

Then in the  new constructor i am usig the following

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal recordId As String)



    'Call to MyBase.New must be the very first in a constructor.

    MyBase.New()


    _recordid = recordId
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.

    InitializeComponent()

    records = threeContext.GetAllDeliverysByRecordId(recordId)
    txtQty.Text = records.Item(0).qty
   End Sub
```

my ok button code is as follows

```
    records.Item(0).qty = txtQty.Text

    Try

        threeContext.dbContext.SaveChanges()



        MessageBox.Show("Changes saved to the database.")
        Close()
```

when i close the edit line box it does not update the data even though im calling the bind method which consits of the following

```
  Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim cfglocation As Int16
    cfglocation = cfb.StoreLocation

    bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.R3Delivery Where u.isprocessed = True AndAlso u.location = 1
                      Select u)


    bs.ResetBindings(True)
    dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
End Sub
```

Comment: You never do anything with the modified value. Note that `invId` is not passed by reference.

Comment: @GertArnold yes i do on the my ok button code  is set it then save the context of all that works its just not saving the data till i close the grid window i think i need to share the context between forms possiblity